# Add failure handling in AWS Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using Lambda to send batch messages to Redshift via Firehose. As per [Firehose API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html), if there is some delivery issue (poisoned message,endpoints down etc), Firehose will keep trying for 24 hrs and delete the message. I would like to move failed message to another queue after X failed attempts  (essentially like [SQS Redrive Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSDeadLetterQueue.html#sqs-dlq)). What's the best way to do this , preferably without cross-checking the target Redshift database ?

Answer (score 0):

From your link, I am assuming you are interested in tracking failures to PutRecord to the Firehose Kinesis stream, and not the Kinesis -> S3 -> Redshift flow.

When you initialize your Firehose client, you can actually specify the number of retries you want to occur. When there's an exception received (failure to PutRecord to the stream), Firehose will automatically try up to the max retries you set; this is done under the hood, in the SDK, so you won't know that your retries have been exceeded until you get the exception bubbling up to your function. When you get this exception, you can assume that the retries have been exceeded. This exception handling can include sending the message to a SQS queue.

You can learn more about your Firehose client configuration here, it's not well known, but is very useful. [Firehose ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html).

Comment: I am looking for failures in Kinesis -> S3 -> Redshift flow. +1 for the client config link though..hope there's something similar in the python sdk .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quiet differently in the below way, not in a straight forward way from firehose.

1. You can have your lambda function call firehose which would write to S3.
2. Create kinesis analytics that reads from firehose.
3. Configure different streams upon kinesis analytics

   1. Successful Records (In-stream) will move to a firehose which will be loaded into redshift.
   2. Error Records (error-stream) will be loaded into a different firehose which will be loaded into S3.

You have successful records loaded into redshift and unsuccessful records filtered to S3.

This is an approach which we follow , let me know if you need any clarifications on this.